# Loop in Javascript, why does "i" iterate this way?

Tags: javascript

Why does the variable "i" not go up as 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 consecutively? "i" stays at 0 ten times.

```
var num = 0;

outermost:
for (var i=0; i < 10; i++) {
    for (var j=0; j < 10; j++) {
        console.log(i, j);
        if (i ==5 && j ==5) {
            break outermost;
        }
        num++;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`i` doesn't change while the inner `j` loop is repeating. When `j` reaches `10`, we exit the inner loop, and then go to the next iteration of the outer loop, which increments `i`.

This is like an odometer: `i` is the 10's digit, `j` is the units digit. The 10's digit stays the same until the units rolls over from 9 to 0.

Comment: +1 for the odometer analogy :-).

Answer (score 1):

Because the inner loop runs ten times while i is 0.

Answer (score -1):

This program worked for me.

It broke out when i and j equal 5 and the output was as expected 0 0, 0 1, ... 1 0, ... 5 5